# How to fix a shallow bump dent?

Tags: body-work, dent

Noticed a shallow bump under the tail light recently and wondering whether there's a DIY way to fix it. I heard that deeper dents could be fixed with a suction cup, but not sure it will have any effect in this case.

Could you share your experience fixing these?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look in your area for PDR (Paintless Dent Repair) - they cover most locations, and come to you. They have special tools for pulling very small dents like that, and don't cost too much.